# Undefinex Index id PHP mySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, undefined-index

Hello I am currently having an issue with my website, I have a basic list of Todo's that are accessed from phpMyAdmin database and I keep getting errors like this.. I cannot find a solution since I don't know what variable should be there

Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\Users\User1\Downloads\COMP1006-W2017-MidTerm\COMP1006-W2017-MidTerm\index.php on line 59

Notice: Undefined index: todolistID in C:\Users\User1\Downloads\COMP1006-W2017-MidTerm\COMP1006-W2017-MidTerm\book_details.php on line 8

I have included a link to my github so you can see the files as they are. Any help is greatly appreciated (Don't worry about it being called Midterm, I simply am using a file I got working with another database and I am trying to replicated the results

https://github.com/AlexandreMelano/COMP1006-MidTerm-200249154

```
<?php
include_once('database.php'); // include the database connection file

/*//////////////////////*/
/* YOUR CODE GOES HERE */
/*/////////////////////*///
$todolistID = $_GET["todolistID"]; // assigns the gameID from the URL
echo $todolistID;
if($todolistID == 0) {
    $todolist = null;
    $isAddition = 1;
} else {
    $isAddition = 0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM todolists WHERE Id = :todolist_id "; // SQL statement
    $statement = $db->prepare($query); // encapsulate the sql statement
    $statement->bindValue(':todolist_id', $todolistID);
    $statement->execute(); // run on the db server
    $book = $statement->fetch(); // returns only one record
    $statement->closeCursor(); // close the connection
}
?>


next page

<?php
include_once('database.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM todolists"; // SQL statement
$statement = $db->prepare($query); // encapsulate the sql statement
$statement->execute(); // run on the db server
$todolists = $statement->fetchAll(); // returns an array
$statement->closeCursor(); // close the connection
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Book List</title>
    <!-- CSS Section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scripts/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scripts/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scripts/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Content/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <h1>Books List</h1>

            <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
            <!-- FIX THE ADD NEW BOOK BUTTON -->
            <!-- /////////////////////////// -->

            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="book_details.php?todolistID=0"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Book</a>
            <br>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Todo</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>

                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                    <?php foreach($todolists as $todolist) : ?>

                            <td><?php echo $todolist['Id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $todolist['TODO'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $todolist['Notes'] ?></td>


                            <!-- //////////////////// -->
                            <!-- MODIFY SECTION BELOW -->
                            <!-- //////////////////// -->




                            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="book_details.php?todolistID=<?php echo $todolist['Id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a></td>

                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="book_delete.php?todolistID=<?php echo $todolist['Id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: past the code here. and please not it has absolutely noting to do with phpMyAdmin, which is just another php script, not a database

Comment: Note for the future: MYSQL is a database! phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to make administrating your MYSQL database easier